# Using the same certificate for SSL communication and for signing EXEs and DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, code-signing, x509certificate

I have a certificate issued by an official organization to be used for SSL communication, can I use the same certificate to sign my EXEs or DLLs.

If not, what is the critiria for the certificate to be used to sign EXEs and DLLs and other binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate usually has usage constraints, basic constraints and extended constraints (extended key usage, EKU). It depends on those settings what you can use it for. These settings can include client and server authorization, code signing (this is what you're interested in), whether you can use your certificate as an intermediate CA, etc.

Here's a nice overview of possible EKU's: http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/x509/extensions/extendedkeyusage.html . And basic constraints: http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/x509/extensions/BasicConstraints.html . The Windows built-in certificate viewer GUI displays all these constraints nicely, in a human readable form, so you don't need to decode OID's or strange field names.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the other answer, X.509 certificates include KeyUsage and ExtKeyUsage extensions, which describe, what the certificate may be used for.

Most (if not all) Certificate Authorities won't issue the certificate valid for both SSL/TLS and for code signing for commercial reasons and also for security reasons.

On the other hand, if you use a self-signed certificate and validate this certificate in your own code, then nothing prevents you from generating the certificate with KeyUsage set to what you need and validating it accordingly.